# Full-page crossfading navigation in html

Tags: javascript, flash, html

I'm attempting to recreate some flash transition effects with html/ajax.  How feasible is it to do a full-page cross-fade?

Answer (score 1):

It's very possible. It should even be a fairly simple task using jQuery and the `fadeTo()` method for instance.

As a side-note, please do not confuse AJAX for anything that it's not. It's actually in no way related to animation or anything like that, but is actually a rather technical and "dull" technique for querying data from a server without having to reload a web page. The method includes asynchronously querying the server, and using XML as a transfer format, hence the name *Asynchronous Javascript And XML*. In the context of creating a crossfade transition, it's completely irrelevant.